# halt on error in a sqlplus script

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus, oracle-sql-developer

I am deploying pl/sql code using several sql files that are called with `@@file`.
If a package got a compilation error the script continues to the end.

Is there a way to stop on every compilation error?

I tried `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE` but the script still continues.

Answer (score 5):

This can't be done without some kind of workaround, so here's one for you.

You can recompile the PL/SQL after creation & raise an exception if the recompilation fails. This will cause SQL*Plus to exit on failure.

For example:

test.sql:

```
create or replace procedure foo
as
begin
  this is an error;
end;
/

exec execute immediate 'alter procedure foo compile'; exception when others then raise_application_error(-20000,'compilation error')
```

Example:

```
[oracle@node1 ~]$ sqlplus phil/phil

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Fri Dec 14 20:45:47 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
SQL> @test.sql

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

BEGIN execute immediate 'alter procedure foo compile'; exception when others then raise_application_error(-20000,'compilation error'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: compilation error
ORA-06512: at line 1


Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
[oracle@node1 ~]$
```